# Can I alter the main loop to 'orderby' a custom callback?

Tags: wp-query, loop, pre-get-posts

I have a custom post type where the `title` is a name, and I want to sort the loop by the last word in `title`, the surname.

I can easily break the names apart and filter by the last word in a custom query, but I don't want to re-write the main loop / pagination for the archive page. Is it possible to pass a callback to the `orderby` param in the action `pre_get_posts` or is this a lost cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't pass a callback function. Callback functions are PHP, so they can't be run in MySQL. For that to work it would need to query the results from the database first, but you'd get the wrong results because they're unsorted.

You would need to use the `posts_orderby` filter to do this as part of the SQL query:

```
add_filter(
    'posts_orderby',
    function( $orderby, $query ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'post_type_name' ) ) {
            $orderby = "SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, ' ', -1) ASC, post_title ASC";
        }
        
        return $orderby;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

That uses the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` MySQL function to order results by everything after the <del>first</del> last space in the post title, and then by the post title so that results with matching surnames are sorted by first name.

Comment: That's brilliant! I may be pushing my luck but many names have multiple spaces (middle initials, titles, etc). Can `SUBSTRING_INDEX` accept a range? (-1, -2, if -2 exists, and so on?)

Comment: Sorry, I believe this will actually be based on everything after the _last_ space. So `-2` would be after the second last space, and so on. Ultimately you'll be better off storing each part of the name separately, since the number of spaces doesn't tell you much. For example, if the name is "Vincent van Gogh", do you want to sort by "van Gogh" or "Gogh"? If it's "van Gogh", then the same sorting won't work for a first name - last name type of name, so you'd need to store the last name separately.

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood the position parameter. I tweaked your code a little bit bc `$query` doesn't seem to be available at that filter point. Thanks for pointing me to `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`!

Comment: I've updated my answer to fix the missing `$query` issue. I needed to set the 4th argument of `add_filter()` to `2`.

Answer (score -1):

Just posting my code for posterity, I made some small changes to @Jacob Peatite's code, if anyone needs a drop-in solution:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', __NAMESPACE__ . '\surname_orderby', 10, 2);
function surname_orderby($args, $wp_query)
{
    //make sure this is not an admin dashboard query.
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }
    //check if this is the main query, rather than a secondary query such as widgets or menus.
    if (!is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    // the wp query at this filter is literally just the orderby value, we need to fetch the queried object
    $queriedObj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    
    if (isset($queriedObj->name) && $queriedObj->name === the_one_I_want ) {
        $args = "SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, ' ', -1) ASC, post_title ASC";
        return $args;
    }
}
```